# how to solve the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

Tags: sql

how to solve this error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

```
SELECT        tblPR.PRNO, tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode, ISNULL(SUM(DISTINCT tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty - SUM(tblPOFromPR.Qty)), tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty) AS PR_Qty
FROM            tblPR INNER JOIN
                         tblPRMaterial ON tblPR.PRNO = tblPRMaterial.PRNO INNER JOIN
                         tblMaterial ON tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblMaterial.MaterialCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         tblPOFromPR ON tblPRMaterial.PRNO = tblPOFromPR.PRNO AND tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblPOFromPR.MaterialCode
WHERE        (tblPR.PRStatus = 1) AND (tblPRMaterial.PRItemStatus = 0) AND (tblPR.PRType = 'PR') AND (tblPR.PRNO = 56548)
GROUP BY tblPR.PRNO, tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode, tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty
ORDER BY tblPR.PRNO
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start.)

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/

Comment: The reason seems obvious -- you have nested `SUM()`.  What you actually want to do is less obvious, so how to fix it is not apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - you need to add `sum(tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty)` in your isnull function

```
    SELECT tblPR.PRNO, tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode, 
   coalesce(SUM(DISTINCT tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty) - SUM(tblPOFromPR.Qty), 
   sum(tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty)) AS PR_Qty
    FROM            tblPR INNER JOIN
                             tblPRMaterial ON tblPR.PRNO = tblPRMaterial.PRNO INNER JOIN
                             tblMaterial ON tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblMaterial.MaterialCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             tblPOFromPR ON tblPRMaterial.PRNO = tblPOFromPR.PRNO AND tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblPOFromPR.MaterialCode
    WHERE        (tblPR.PRStatus = 1) AND (tblPRMaterial.PRItemStatus = 0) AND (tblPR.PRType = 'PR') AND (tblPR.PRNO = 56548)
    GROUP BY tblPR.PRNO, tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode
    ORDER BY tblPR.PRNO
```

Answer (score 0):

number of column in selection and group by must be same

```
    SELECT  tblPR.PRNO,
 tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode, 
ISNULL(SUM(tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty) - SUM(tblPOFromPR.Qty), sum(tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty)) AS PR_Qty
    FROM            tblPR INNER JOIN
                             tblPRMaterial ON tblPR.PRNO = tblPRMaterial.PRNO INNER JOIN
                             tblMaterial ON tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblMaterial.MaterialCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             tblPOFromPR ON tblPRMaterial.PRNO = tblPOFromPR.PRNO AND tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblPOFromPR.MaterialCode
    WHERE        (tblPR.PRStatus = 1) AND (tblPRMaterial.PRItemStatus = 0) AND (tblPR.PRType = 'PR') AND (tblPR.PRNO = 56548)
    GROUP BY tblPR.PRNO, tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode
    ORDER BY tblPR.PRNO,tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Aggregate` cannot contain another `Aggregate` expression on it.. Maybe you can use explicit to do `Sum` Operation..

```
SELECT 
  PRNO,
  PRMaterialCode,
  ISNULL(SUM(SUM_PR), PRReqdQty) AS PR_QTY
FROM
(SELECT        
  tblPR.PRNO, 
  tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode,
  tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty, 
  DISTINCT tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty - SUM(tblPOFromPR.Qty) AS SUM_PR
FROM 
  tblPR 
  INNER JOIN tblPRMaterial ON tblPR.PRNO = tblPRMaterial.PRNO 
                           AND (tblPRMaterial.PRItemStatus = 0)
  INNER JOIN tblMaterial ON tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblMaterial.MaterialCode 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPOFromPR ON tblPRMaterial.PRNO = tblPOFromPR.PRNO 
                              AND tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode = tblPOFromPR.MaterialCode
WHERE 
  (tblPR.PRStatus = 1) 
  AND (tblPR.PRType = 'PR') 
  AND (tblPR.PRNO = 56548)
GROUP BY 
  tblPR.PRNO, 
  tblPRMaterial.PRMaterialCode, 
  tblPRMaterial.PRReqdQty
ORDER BY 
  tblPR.PRNO) AS Derived_Table
GROUP BY
  PRNO,
  PRMaterialCode,
  PRReqdQty
ORDER BY
  PRNO
```